# Object rotate in a strange way

Tags: transforms

today i run into another problem. i dont know how i have done it (probably i clicked sth what i should not click) - anyway - since that moment my objects are behaving totally different when i try to rotate them. the objects are now rotating around the pivot point but they keep their alignment - not sure if i am clear. eg. if u would rotate a plane which is lies flat on the ground it makes the rotation but the faces of the plane would still be up and dont which shouldn't be the case with the "normal" rotation that i know. so i want to understand what i have done (because this kind of rotation could be also usefull sometimes for me) and how can i return it in the case it happens again.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have turned on "Individual origin" Pivot point.

[image]